# Is it okay to suggest an edit adding a link to a mirror?

Tags: discussion, editing

Overtime, some links get broken ([some data for stack overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300916/395857)). Is it okay to suggest an edit adding a link to a mirror?

Example: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17892

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, yes, although it is encouraged that people do provide some summary or paraphrasing (quoting is okay too but not huge swaths of direct copying) and use the link as a reference rather than as the answer.

The purpose of doing this is preserving the information of what the link contained so that we don't end up in situations where the answer becomes unsubstantiated in the future due to link rot.